# Difficulties finding a Java regex equivalent to a JavaScript regex

Tags: java, regex, string

So, what I am trying to do is:

I have a string:

```
Special Skills:
someText
could range 
through multiple lines

Special Abilities:
another
someText

Background:
multiline
text
```

I've already managed to come up with the following regex. It works perfectly in JavaScript according to regexr.com, but not in Java, according to Intellij's built-in Check-Regex and freeformatter.com.

```
Special Abilities:\n(.*\n)+?(Special Skills:|Background:)
```

The expression should, first off, extract

```
Special Skills:
someText
could range 
through multiple lines
```

Mind that the both the sections "Special Abilities" and "Background" are optional.

Since I am kindoff stuck here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `"(?d)Special Abilities:\n((?:.*\n)*?)(Special Skills:|Background:)"`. Note your text above has no `:` after `Background`. Probably you will want to remove it from the pattern, too. See [**this regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rtgS1Q/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sadly, the program tells me that no match was found.

Comment: Please show the code for us to repro the same issue. Also, if those two values are optional, you need `"(?d)Special Abilities:\n((?:.*\n)*?)(Special Skills:|Background:|$)"`

Comment: Aand this fixed it for me, thank you very much  @WiktorStribiżew! Actually, mind to post it as an answer so we get this question closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add the end-of-string(line) anchor `$` as an alternative to the alternation group at the end of the pattern, make sure the `.` matches carriage returns with `(?d)` `Pattern.UNIX_LINES` embedded flag and wrap `(.*\n)+?` with a capturing group to capture all text it matches into 1 group (and the `(.*\n)+?` can be changed into a non-capturing group):

```
(?d)Special Abilities:\r?\n((?:.*\n)*?)(Special Skills:|Background:|$)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rtgS1Q/3).

**Details**

- `(?d)` - `.` now matches any char but a newline
- `Special Abilities:` - a literal text
- `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF line ending
- `((?:.*\n)*?)` - Group 1: zero or more, but as few as possible, repetitionsof 0+ chars other than LF symbol and then an LF symbol
- `(Special Skills:|Background:|$)` - either of the three alternatives: `Special Skills:`, `Background:` or end of string (`$`).

An alternative expression:

```
(?ms)Special Abilities:\r?\n(.*?)(^Special Skills:|^Background:|\Z)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rtgS1Q/4)

Here, `(?ms)` defines the multiline and dotall modes (`^` will match start of a line here and `.` will match all symbols). Instead of `$`, we need to use `\Z` - end of string anchor.